# Database architecture / transaction commit

Tags: java, database, scala

How are transaction commits usually implemented? I mean I'm having a transaction log (or more logs for different page-types) which are persisted in a BerkeleyDB database depending on some buffer caching strategies (a simple Guava cache). During a transaction commit the transaction logs are read and written to the data-file (currently a single write transaction is only permitted).

However these commits are heavyweight and thus seem to be a bottleneck.

My idea:
The transaction logs are at first flushed to disk (but also held in memory) during a commit, then the records from the transaction logs are read one by one and appended to the "normal" data file. Afterwards the entries are deleted from the transaction log. Now I should be able to replay a crashed transaction based on the fact that if the transaction log still exists the remaining entries first must be written to the data file, before a new write transaction is able to proceed.

However, as stated besides the redo-operation somehow doesn't work as expected the commit itself is a bottleneck, because it also must write the changed paths/pages of a B+-tree like page structure to disk, besides the actual data pages.

Maybe one could also issue the commit in a dedicated thread in a thread pool and upcoming transactions first check a flag in the transaction-log, indicating if the transaction is commited and then first try to read from the transaction-logs and then from the data file.

For the interested ones: https://github.com/JohannesLichtenberger/sirix

I'm currently also looking for other open source developers which might spend some spare time ;-)

I haven't found many literature about how to implement a transaction system. Note that the system supports versioning and only appends new versions after a commit.

Do you think my second approach is working? Otherwise what is the "state of the art"? However, if it's too complicated to implement, I think I'm prioritizing other tasks at first.

Or maybe provide an asynchronous commit...   trx.asynchCommit() for applications which need to provide very fast updates and just eventually allow read access to the stored revision. But then the writing might not be sequential as another transaction can also commit, but ok, it's designed for use with flash-disks and especially random reads occur nontheless, but writes are usually sequential.

Comment: Or maybe provide an asynchronous commit...   trx.asynchCommit() and just eventually allow read access to the stored revision. But then the writing might not be linear as another transaction can also commit, but ok, it's designed for use with flash-disks and especially random reads occur nontheless.

Comment: Hm, for some distribution things I'd like to use Akka in the future, but maybe only in the sirix-distributed maven bundle. And I'd like to provide a clean Java- and Scala-API, but I think it's more an issue the other way round. If I'd have enough time, I'd probably reimplement everything in Scala ;-)